# NHibernate Fetch Returning Wrong Row Count

Tags: nhibernate

I have an API set up in my project for a grid to call to get audit records to display to an admin. The grid has infinite scrolling set up and uses oData built into mvc4. So, it will make a call to the api with $top equal to the number of rows it is supposed to get and $skip set to get to the proper page.

Inside the API, I make this call to nhibernate to get an IQueryable to return for MVC4 to do it's dark oData magic:

`m_session.Query<AuditInfo>().FetchMany(x => x.Parameters).Fetch(x => x.AuditType).Fetch(x => x.Status)`

In this, AuditInfo has a collection of parameters hanging off it, as well as lookup tables for the type and status.

My issue is that if I ask for 30 rows, it will return some number <= 30. I've been able to trace this a little bit, and the problem seems to be that nhibernate has the `TOP` and `JOIN` statements in the same query, so when an audit has more than one parameter on it, it creates a copy of the audit to hold the second parameter for returning it. Doing this takes up a space in the TOP(30) that the query allows for. Then, when it gets back to nhibernate, it appears that it merges these rows, leaving me with a collection that has less records than I wanted.

My question here is: **How can I set this call up so I can get an accurate number of records without resorting to fetching the parameters separately and having n+1 queries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basicly you can't easyly because that is how sql works. leave out the FetchMany and it should work using Select N+1. To remedy that you can tweak the collection batch-size so NH will load more than one collection of the same type at once.